# Loading animations not working in Edge

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I have a loading animation that works perfectly fine in chrome and firefox but not at all in IE10 or edge.

This is my html:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1">
    <symbol id="s-circle">
        <circle r="10" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
    </symbol>
    <g>
        <#list 1..9 as i>
           <g class="g-circle">
                 <use href="#s-circle"/>
            </g>  
        </#list>
    </g>
</svg>
```

and this is my scss:

```
$max: 9;
$angle: 360/$max;
$size: 160px;
$fill: $grey;

.cart__spinner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
}

svg {
    height: $size;
    width: $size;
    margin: 0 4em 4em;
    overflow: visible;
}

@function transform($item: 1){
    $base: rotate(#{-$angle*$item}deg) translate(5px, 5px);
    @return $base;
}

.g-circle {
    transform-origin: $size/2 $size/2;

    fill: $fill;
    animation: opacity 1.2s linear infinite;

    @for $item from 1 through $max {
        &:nth-child(#{$max}n + #{$item}) {
            animation-delay: -#{$item/10}s;
            transform: transform($item) scale(.9);
            -ms-transform: transform($item) scale(.9);
        }
    }
}



@keyframes opacity {
    0% {
      fill-opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      fill-opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes transform {
    10% {
        transform-origin: 70px 70px;
        transform: scale(.75);
    }
}
```

In IE10 or edge, there is just one dot on the page and not animation.
Can someone please explain why this is happening. Di I need to explicitly add support for IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured my problem is that IE does not support animations on svg.